# Windows Phone 8 - browser ignoring jQuery .change function?

Tags: jquery, windows-phone-8

I am using jQuery Mobile (along with jQuery) to create a mobile website.  This is NOT using jQuery Windows Phone UI.

I have created two select boxes, "**bpSelect**" and "**msSelect**".
The data for msSelect is based upon the choice in bpSelect.

Once the user makes a choice in bpSelect, an ajax call is made to the backend DB, and data is then passed back to the page in JSON format.  The options for msSelect are created and a "refresh" is called to display it.

**All works fine in any desktop web browser, and on an iPhone or Android device.**
On my WIndows Phone (Lumia 920), the msSelect box never gets created.

It seems as if the Windows Phone is not calling  **$('#bpSelect').change(function()**  on the page when I make a selection.
When I put an "alert" inside this call, it is triggered on every device but the Windows Phone 8 browser.

Any ideas here?  I have tried numerous things like using "data-ajax = false" to get to the page, along with "document.ready()" instead of "pageinit" but nothing seems to work.  It seems as if the Windows Phone browser is ignoring certain jQuery code.

All my functions are inside the  **$('#createCarPage').bind('pageinit', function()**  at the top of page.
This sits inside the **data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="createCarPage"**  DIV tag

There are several other things that the Windows Phone seems to ignore like **.selectmenu('disable')**  for example, but for now I'm just trying to get the select box to work.

The basics of my code is below.  Any help would be appreciated.  I'm really stumped on this one.

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

<body>
<div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="createCarPage" class="rf-background">

<script type="text/javascript">

$('#createCarPage').bind('pageinit', function()
{
    $("#exTypeOptions input[type='radio']").checkboxradio('disable');

    $('#bpSelect').selectmenu('disable');
    $('#msSelect').selectmenu('disable');

    $('#bpSelect').on('change', function ()
    {
         $("#msSelect option").each(function(index, option) {
                 $(option).remove();
             });

        var listServlet = "/messages/makeList"; 

         $.ajax({
                   url: listServlet,
                   data: { bp:$('#bpSelect').val() },
                   dataType: "json",
                   success: function(data)
                   { 
                      $('#msSelect').append('<option value=>' + 'Select...'+ '</option>');

                    for (var i=0; i<data.model.length; i++)
                      {
                        $('#msSelect').append('<option value="' + data.model[i] + '">' + data.model[i]+ '</option>');
               }

                        $('#msSelect').selectmenu('enable');
                $('#msSelect').selectmenu('refresh');

                   },
                   error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                   {

                   }

                 });     

        });

      }); 

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured this out.  After researching jQuery and jQuery Mobile, I could see no reason why the browser would be ignoring the jQuery code.  The jQuery website stated that it supported the Windows Phone browser so there must be another problem.

There was...  Zepto.js

In addition to using jQuery, I am also making use of the responsive framework **Foundation 4**. 
I discovered that Foundation uses Zepto.js instead of jQuery.
The Zepto.js site states the following...

> **Zepto is expected to work in every modern browser and browser-like
>   environment, except for Internet Explorer.**

The Foundation website says you can subsitite jQuery for Zepto with no issues.
When I removed the reference to Zepto... problem solved.

Foundation states that they switched to Zepto as a "lighter substitute" for jQuery.

Personally, I'll take a heavier implementation that actually works!

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: it would be interesting to see if this changes with GDR3 & IE11